# PHP - Counting Leap Days in Date Range

Tags: php, date

I am trying to count the number of leap days within a date range.

This is what I have so far (adopted code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474098/checking-if-theres-a-leap-day-in-a-timerange))

```
<?php
$date_from = strtotime('2019-06-01');
$date_to = strtotime('2021-05-30');
$leapday_count = 0;

for($year=$date_from; $year<=$date_to; $year=strtotime('next year', $year)) {

    if (date('L', $year)) {
         $leapday_count++;
    }   

}

echo $leapday_count;
?>
```

Here is what I need help with:

1. The above code does only look at the years of the start and end date. For example it does **not** take into consideration if the start date is after Feb 29th. How can I make sure that it really takes the entire dates into consideration and not only the years of the dates?

   - Example expected result: 0 leap days between 2020-03-01 2024-02-28
   - Example expected result: 2 leap days between 2020-02-28 2024-03-01

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop doing date maths. It's hard.

Use datetime and diff

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Example there

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');

$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

 echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

to exactly answer the question.

```
$start = new DateTime('2020-03-01');
$end = new DateTime('2024-02-28');
$interval = ("last day of feb next year");

$current = clone $start;
$leapYears = 0;
while ($current->modify("last day of feb") && $current <= $end) {
    if ($current->format('d') == 29 && $current > $start) {
        $leapYears++;
    }
    $current->modify("+1 year");
}
```

Comment: I don't see how I can use datetime and diff to calculate the number of leap days in a range. Can you please elaborate?